# Display the value of a range slider with activeadmin and formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic, activeadmin

I am using activeadmin with a range field :

```
ActiveAdmin.register Card do
  form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
        f.inputs "Traitements" do
          f.input :treatment_chlore, :as => :range, :in => 0..10, :step => 0.5
        end
        f.buttons
     end
end
```

I have the slider showing well but i don't see the value of the slider. When we move the slider, i want to see its value on a :hint.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3):

I needed the same thing -- here's how I ended up solving it (only tested on Chrome. YMMV)

*(I'm not crazy about the inline javascript handler here. If anyone has a better solution for use with active_admin, please comment.)*

```
ActiveAdmin.register Card do
  form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|

    f.inputs "Traitements" do
      f.input :treatment_chlore, {
        :as => :range, 
        :in => 0..10, 
        :step => 0.5, 
        :html_input => {:oninput => "card_treatment_chlore_output.value = this.valueAsNumber",
        :hint => %Q{value: <output for="card_treatment_chlore" name="card_treatment_chlore_output">#{resource.treatment_chlore}</output> }.html_safe
      }
    end

    f.buttons
  end
end
```

Comment: May be, there are another way of these?

Answer (score 0):

```
f.input :discount_percent, :as => :range, :in => 0..100, :step => 0.5
```

coffeescript file:

```
$ ->
  text = $("label[for='frequency_discount_percent']").text()
  $("label[for='frequency_discount_percent']").text("#{text} (#{parseFloat($("#frequency_discount_percent").val()).toFixed(1)})")
  $("#frequency_discount_percent").change ->
    $("label[for='frequency_discount_percent']").text("#{text} (#{parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(1)})")
```

So i have changed the value of label, seems not bad at all