# How to display value in slider in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Hi folks I am having issues in jquery slider in ruby on rails. if anyone knows the answer please help me. Actually my code for jquery slider is

```
                  <div id="report">
                        <div class="slide">
                    <%= range_field_tag(:maturity_level_score, assess.attributes["maturity_level_score"], in: 1..10 , name: 'maturity_score[]')%>
                  </div>
                  </div>
```

am using range_field_tag for sliders. so it provided me sliders like without the range value

but I want to show the range values(which I mentioned in the code) over the slider.

Is there any possible to add to display range values in my slider?? 
Is there any code to add in my range_field_tag??...please reply anyone if you have suggestions. Thanks in advance. any help would be so grateful to me.

Comment: Please go through this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311815/display-the-value-of-a-range-slider-with-activeadmin-and-formtastic][1]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this answer - 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26739955/3556317

You can apply the same jQuery and change the CSS according to your styling needs. The `range_field_tag` will convert into an HTML `<input type="range"/>` so the code will work. You will just have to add the classes to the field.

Here is the code for what you want.

1. HTML

   ```
   <div class="range-wrapper">
     <input type="range" min="0" max="10" id="myRange"/>
     <div class="text">1</div>
   </div>
   <div class="range-wrapper">
     <input type="range" min="0" max="10" id="mySecondRange"/>
     <div class="text">1</div>
   </div>
   ```
2. jQuery

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     updateRangeValue($('input[type=range]'));
     $('input[type=range]').on('input change',function(){
       var input = $(this);
       updateRangeValue(input);
     });    
   });
   function updateRangeValue(input){
     var value = input.val();
     var maximum = input.attr('max'); 
     var inputWidth = input.width();
     var offLeft = Math.floor((value / maximum) * inputWidth - (((value / maximum) * inputWidth - inputWidth/2) / 100) * 24);    
     var offLeftAbs = value == maximum ? input.offset().left - 15 + offLeft : input.offset().left - 10 + offLeft;
     input.next('.text').css({'left': offLeftAbs +'px'});
     input.next('.text').html(value);
   }
   ```
3. CSS

   ```
   .range-wrapper {
     overflow: hidden;
     padding: 5px 0px;    
   } 
   .range-wrapper > div {
     position: relative;
     top: -15px;
     width: 5px;
   }
   .range-wrapper > .text {
     pointer-events: none;
   }
   input[type=range]{
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     background: #eee;
   }
   input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
     width: 300px;
     height: 5px;   
     border: none;
     border-radius: 3px;
   }
   input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     border: 1px solid #e95e57;
     height: 32px;
     width: 32px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     background: white;
     margin-top: -14px;
     cursor: pointer;
   }
   input[type=range]:focus {
     outline: none;
     background: #ccc;
   }
   ```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vishalatthehorizon/vk5yyr8s/1/) link.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but here i didnt use any  juery. because range_field_tag did the same.

Comment: Hey Vishal, I have gone through the link which you provided. but I don't want to use colours for sliders. can you cut the code and send it here?? because I am confused from where I have to start.

Comment: I have edited the code to make it work the way you want. However this is now a partly redundant answer on SO (which doesn't really comply with SO's standard). I advise you to next time go through code first, understand it and try to customize it for your specific need. You will not learn otherwise.

Comment: OK Ok thank you..I already edited and run the code given by you..the edited code done by me is same as you edited..we both edited the code same way..but still am not getting solution...Don't know why